# Loading More Button Not Working Consistently on Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re as re
import time
import os
import sys

url = 'https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/Python 3.9/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-close-btn-container"]/a').click()

loadingButton = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "LOAD MORE")))
maxTires = 200;

while loadingButton:
    loadingButton.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a")))
    loadElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-mainpagecontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a')
    if len(loadElems)>0:
        loadingButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-mainpagecontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a')
        tiresLoaded = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#block-mainpagecontent > div > div > div.views-element-container.block.block-views.block-views-blockall-athletes-page > div > div > ul > li > a"))
    else:
        print("Loaded all the tires")
        break
    if tiresLoaded >= maxTires:
        print (tiresLoaded + " are loaded successfully.")
        break
my_hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/a/span")))]
windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle

for my_href in my_hrefs:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    windows_after = driver.window_handles
    new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(link.text)
    nickname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div').text
    fighter_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h1').text
    status = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
    Rank_Division_Record = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/text()')
    age = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
    leg_reach = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]')
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(windows_before)
driver.quit()
```

I keep getting the error

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (600, 685). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)

I keep increasing the amount of time in waiting prior to clicking but this error still appears. I appreciate any insight anyone can give one this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the cookies popup is getting display when the screen is getting loaded so first handle the cookie by using `explicitWait`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Accept Cookies']"))).click()
```

Then you can click on the load more button by using below `explicitWait`

```
 WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Load More']"))).click()
```

**Update**

Can you execute the script in the maximize browser mode
`driver.maximize_window()` also when I executed the script it was running fine till the last page where the `Load More` button is not available and it throws `TimeoutException` also try to execute the script in the `incognito` mode for the avoiding the cache issue

So to prove my point just check the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ifxi.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPGdg.png

Comment: The code I have in there for the cookie seems to be doing the trick, in fact the load more button works but I get this error after about page 3/93. I just tried your code but again I got the same error at page 3. I have been able to run it successfully one time, and gotten to about page 50 as well, but today it has not been able to get past page 3.

Comment: @dontdownvotemeplease what I analyze is when you run your script in `driver.maximize_window()` it consistently running till the last page where the `Load More` button is not available so it through the TimeOutException  try to handle it and also try to clear the browser cache or execute it in Incognito mode as sometime when we run the script it's taking more time than usual time to load

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the element is overlapped by another element and hence the click() method is not working. Actually it is clicking but the click is done on overlapped element.

Can you try
driver.find_element_by_xpath().send_keys(keys.ENTER)